# Is Sci-Hub a stolen data site and does this pose a problem for recommending a Sci-Hub link?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

In a discussion in comments below [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24441/12102) I said things to the effect that if you want recommend someone click on a Sci-Hub link you should also mention that Sci-Hub is based (in part) on stealing data from computer systems, so you might want to think twice before you give them a click; in part obviously due to safety concerns since they are said to [steal data from computer systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sci-Hub), or at least that's how I read some statements in the Wikipedia article.

Comments by a security professional suggest that wouldn't be necessary because they would be surprised if the site was as unsafe as I suspected (paraphrasing).

I recommended that they post an answer to [What's our policy on sci-hub links?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1033/12102) but they declined as it's outside the scope of that question.

So I've added this question to provide a venue.

**Question:** Is Sci-Hub a stolen data site and does this pose a problem for recommending a Sci-Hub link?

Comment: Some of the content may be accessed using stolen credentials, but referring to it as a "stolen data site" is a bit misleading. Anyway, this is a duplicate of [this post](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1033/30050). That already answers the policy on recommending it.

Comment: @forest you just said [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24423/is-it-possible-to-extend-high-speed-data-transmission-with-lasers-to-the-distanc/24441?noredirect=1#comment121858_24441) that the other question was not suitable for an answer to this question, now suggesting it is a duplicate is saying the opposite.Your words: "The linked meta has nothing to do with the safety of Sci-Hub"

Comment: Right. If you're asking about how safe the site is, it belongs on [security.se], not a site meta. If you're asking about the policy that Space.SE has on the site, then it's a duplicate. Anyway, I declined to answer because there was already a post which encompassed my feelings on the subject. I upvoted it instead.

Comment: No, "Is recommending a Sci-Hub link a good idea? Should we mention that it's a stolen data site if we do?" is a 100% pure meta question.

Comment: The first part of the question is a duplicate. The answer was yes, we can post Sci-Hub links. The second part of the question relies on a misunderstanding of how Sci-Hub gets its credentials. It does **not** steal data from users who visit the site or attack user's computers. If it did, it would be considered a malicious site and would be blocked by antivirus vendors. It would also quickly lose all the support it has.

Comment: @forest that would be a reasonable answer, and I'd like to see it voted on. Consider posting?

Comment: I reworded the question to avoid it being a partial duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether or not recommending Sci-Hub links is already dealt with in [another question](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1033/30050). As for mentioning that the site is dangerous and will steal your data, that is based on a misunderstanding about how the site obtains the credentials it uses to bypass paywalls. It does not attack its visitors, nor does it download anything malicious onto your computer. What happens is that it gets donations of credentials, which it uses to log into paywalled journals and access papers. Some of these credentials are alleged to have been stolen. The site does not, however, attack its users and it is not dangerous for anyone to visit.

If Sci-Hub attacked its users and stole data from their computers, then the policy on its links would be different. The site would be banned for malware distribution or as a security risk. If that ever happens, then I expect all the links to be purged and the site would never recover from its tarnished reputation.